# OAuth2Authenticator with Google and FaceBook on Mac

Tags: macos, oauth, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am developing an application in mac using xamarin which needs to be connected with Google and FaceBook. I tried to use OAuth2Authenticator to Authenticate the users  using below code:

```
 var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
                clientId: "myId.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                clientSecret: "mysecred",
                scope: "document",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri ("myredirect:oob"),
                accessTokenUrl: new Uri ("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"),
                getUsernameAsync: null
            );
```

When I tried to get the url by using the method auth.GetUI() it throws

> error "WebAuthenticator not supported on this platform."

Is there any other way to connect Gmail or Facebook within the Mac application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick an open-source library like this https://github.com/clancey/simpleauth

Or you have to write a binding of some existing MacOS library, but it's going to be a real pain.